# Django admin sorting

Tags: django

In my admin.py is there a way to sort this data set by latest date? As you can see below it's sorting alphabetically.

---Model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=48, unique=True)
        data = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

---Admin:

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the queryset used for an m2m field via [formfield_for_manytomany](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "data":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Product.objects.order_by('date_created')
        return super(TagAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

---

If you would like a global, non admin specific ordering, you can override `get_query_set` in your [model manager.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
         return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('date_created') 
         # this would affect any ordering using this model including admin.
```

Comment: Do you need clarification somewhere? I can try to help

Comment: Well, since I can't see your models, I just guesstimated that you have an m2m field called `tagged_site`, the m2m model being `TaggedSite`, and that is has a field `date_created` to order by. Those are the 3 variables. Insert your actual m2m field, actual Site model needing ordering, and the field to order by and you're good to go. Oh, I see you added the models. I'll just update the post.

Comment: You're the man! Got it to work. Thanks. Wouldn't have figured it out without your help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `data` M2M points to a model that has a date field to order by, you can easily sort in your `admin.py` relevant Admin class. In this case, your model is `Product`, so if `Product` has a date field, you can use it to order the admin changelist.

Let's say your Admin class is the following:

```
@admin.register(Tag)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'data']
    ordering = ['data__date_field_name']
```

The line `ordering = ['data__date_field_name']` will order by the `data` object's `date_field_name` field. `date_field_name` can be w/e the field is actually called that represents the `data` object's date field. Alphabetically or numerically will be depending on the field. Uses the field's normal ordering method. You can also do `ordering = ['-data__date_field_name']` which will sort in descending order.

**Source:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering